# Control 2 DMCircularScrollViews by scrolling 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using the DMCircularScrollView library found here: https://github.com/malcommac/DMCircularScrollView

What the library accomplishes is an "infinite" scroll view that loops back to the beginning.

I have 2 DMCircularScrollViews, each with 3 items. The width of the items in each is different, though. In the first one they are all scrollViewWidth/2, and in the second one they are equal to the width of the scroll view. How can I control the second scroll view by scrolling the first one? Ie: I move the first scroll view to select the second item, how can I automatically make the second scroll view animated as I move the first?

After reading other posts on linking to regular UIScrollViews I have tried implementing the delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` and setting the content offset of the second scroll view, but that method did not work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I implemented the following methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSLog(@"Test: %f", testScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.x);

    if(scrollView == threePageScrollView.scrollView) {
        //[testScrollView relayoutPageItems:NSUIntegerMax];
        [testScrollView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Third: %f", threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.x);
        [testScrollView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.x*2, threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
        [testScrollView reloadInputViews];

    }

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)sv {

    [testScrollView relayoutPageItems:NSUIntegerMax];

    if(sv == threePageScrollView.scrollView) {

        [testScrollView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Third: %f", threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.x);
        [testScrollView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.x*2, threePageScrollView.scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
        [testScrollView reloadInputViews];

    }
    //[self delegateSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:) toDelegateWithArgument:sv];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sv
{
    [testScrollView relayoutPageItems:NSUIntegerMax];
    //[self delegateSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) toDelegateWithArgument:sv];
    testScrollView.currentPageIndex = threePageScrollView.currentPageIndex;
}
```

Where `threePageScrollView` is the one I am scrolling, and `testScrollView` is the one that is being animated through code.